# Question regarding gksudo/gksu

Tags: ssh, gedit, remote, aws, gksudo

I am on a Windows PC and tried connecting to AWS running Ubuntu. I tried opening a file using gedit, was unsuccessful. Someone suggested MobaExtreme. Then I had to install gksudo in the server and tried gedit in the MobaExtreme shell and this solved the problem.

**What I am really wondering is:**

1. Why couldn't I open gedit in the first place(This involved discussion about using ssh -X, and something regarding display not set)
2. What does gksudo establish? (Can you elaborate on 'Owner is not the root'? I have no understanding of this concept).

Edit: Suggested merge answer only part of the question. I can accept the merge but I feel I'll not know other parts which I am curious about!

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. Display not set most likely has nothing to do with gksudo/gksu.

Comment: What file did you try to open?

Comment: @muru not really. I understand how to do it. Just don't understand what is happening.

Comment: @user68186 I understand your frustration. I'm kinda a noob. So I'm just stating all the problem I've seen from google search.

Comment: @WhatIfTheyGetMe you did read the first two lines of the top answer, didn't you?

Comment: @steeldriver Simple text file. Works with nano, I just wanted the GUI to navigate better.

Comment: Possible relevant question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications

Comment: @user68186 thanks man. I'm resolving the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For point#2:

1. gksudo is used to pop up the password prompt in a GUI window, no matter whether the application is GUI or CLI.
2. sudo, asks for the password at the terminal instead of in a GUI window, regardless of the type of application being run.
3. In scripts that don't run in an interactive terminal, gksu is the easiest way to get a user-entered password straight to sudo.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Nisheet, but you have elaborated more about sudo vs gksudo. Can you tell me why I **have** to use gksudo and not 
sudo gedit file_name